# opening .ccproj file in VS 2012 Express for web

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

how can i open solution which is being developed using trial version of Visual Studio 2012 Professional in Visual Studio 2012 Express for web?

When i try to do so, i get an error stating the solution you are trying to open is incompatible with this version of the application. Open this solution with another version which supports this type of solution.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2012 Express For Web wouldn't do alone, in order to open an Azure project with it you have to install the [Azure SDK](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/azure-tools/) **[after](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/azure/GetStarted.aspx)** you have installed the VS.

Comment: that's being done without mentioning it actually.
its some other issue!

Comment: What was the type of the original solution?