# Azure .ccproj is not supported by this version of application

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-cloud-services

Recently started developing azure cloud services via visual studio 2013 ultimate, last week everything was working fine and I could create a .ccprog file for my cloud service. I decided to format my PC on monday so re-installed VS2013 and the azure SDK v2.5 oof which I was using before but now when I try and create a new azure cloud service project and select the WCF service web role I get a error saying that "it cannot be created due to the .ccproj file not supported by this version of application. please use a version that supports this type of project file." I think that VS isn't recognizing the SDK but not sure, when I select help the VS site says please update your version of VS but it is already the latest VS2013.4, any help would be great, thanks

Comment: no its a .ccproj (Azure cloud service file) still need to edit the typo

Comment: Similar question [opening .ccproj file in VS 2012 Express for web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646245/opening-ccproj-file-in-vs-2012-express-for-web) has an idea  to install expected version of SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your csproj holds a version of an old Azure SDK version. So you should update it.

Here a quick step by step:

```
1) Unload the project file (Right click on project, click "Unload project")
2) Edit the project file (Right click on unloaded project, click "Edit X.csproj")
3) Change the product version to 2.5
<ProductVersion>2.5</ProductVersion>
4) Change the Azure tools version to 2.5
<CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)MicrosoftVisualStudiov$(VisualStudioVersion)Windows Azure Tools2.5</CloudExtensionsDir>
5) Save the project file, and reload the project
6) This should activate the conversion wizard which will then make changes to your .csdef file, adding the following schema version attribute:
<ServiceDefinition name="SentinelWebAzure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-05.1.7">
NOTE: If you are getting a build error complaining about the schema version, that is because you dont have the right cloud extension dir setting applied.  See step #4.
```

Source: http://mvolo.com/visual-studio-build-and-publishing-problems-after-upgrading-to-azure-1-7-sdk/

Comment: thanks for the reply but I cant unload a project file as its not creating one, I unloaded an old .ccprog file from when it worked and in the solution explorer it says "the application is not installed"